# Where do we place assets (like pictures) and how do we load them on a React + Flux web app component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, assets, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm creating a React + Flux web app with a file structure that looks like this:

```
MyApp
|---
|---scripts
    |---app.jsx
    |---actions
    |---components
        |---HomePage.react.jsx
        |---NotFoundPage.react.jsx  
        |--- ...etc
    |---dispatcher
    |---stores
```

1) Where do I place public assets like pictures, videos, text files or whatever..

2) Is there a standard/neat way to load them? All I've found is [this](https://github.com/juancabrera/react-asset-loader) library but there must be something more people use.

Comment: Depends on the size of your project.. small projects I just dump them all in a `/public` folder (maybe broken into `/img`, `/media` etc), and for large projects I usually dish them up via a NodeJS server (or similar)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a `dist` or `public` folder where all asset are kept. When I release the app, the bundles are saved in the `dist` folder.

For example:

```
MyApp
|-- app
|    |---app.jsx
|    |---actions
|    |---components
|        |---HomePage.react.jsx
|        |---NotFoundPage.react.jsx  
|        |--- ...etc
|    |---dispatcher
|    |---stores
|-- public
     | -- js -- bunlde.js
     | -- img -- images
     | -- css -- app.css
```

**Is there a standard/neat way to load them? All I've found is this library but there must be something more people use.**

You can just include them in the index.html. However, recently I've been bundling the css into the javascript file so that I have one single file. 
You can do that with:

- webpack: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader
- browserify: https://github.com/cheton/browserify-css